# Display Posts by Views (Popular Posts Widget)

Tags: widgets, post-meta

I am trying to display the most popular posts based off of [this](http://www.scratchinginfo.net/display-popular-posts-by-views-without-a-plugin-in-wordpress/), but I don't think it is working properly. When you view a post it seems to add 1 view to each of them, not just the unique ID.

```
<?php

class SEM_Podcast_Widget extends WP_Widget
{   
    protected $defaults;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Set the default widget settings
        $this->defaults = array(
            'title'         => '',
            'showdate'      => '1',
            'posts_cat'     => '',
            'postid'        => '',
            'showsummary'   => 1,
            'showfeatured'  => 1,
            'featuretype'   => 'latest'
        );

        // Widget settings
        $widget_ops = array(
        'classname' => 'featuredpodcast',   // CSS classname for widget div
        'description' => 'Displays the latest / featured podcast with excerpt and player.'  // Description shown in the WP Admin on the widgets page
        );

        // Widget control settings
        $control_ops = array(
        'id_base' => 'featured-podcast',
        'width' => 250,
        'height' => 250
        );

        // Create the widget
        $this->WP_Widget('featured-podcast', 'SEM Geeks Featured Podcast Widget', $widget_ops, $control_ops);
    }


    // prints the form on the widgets page
    public function form ($instance)
    {

        // Merge with defaults
        $instance = wp_parse_args((array) $instance, $this->defaults);
    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title') ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title') ?> " value="<?php echo $instance['title'] ?>" size="25">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('showdate'); ?>">Date:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('showdate') ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('showdate') ?> " value="1" <?php checked($instance['showdate']) ?>>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('showsummary'); ?>">Show Summary:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('showsummary') ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('showsummary') ?> " value="1" <?php checked($instance['showsummary']) ?>>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('posts_cat'); ?>">Podcast Category:</label>
    <?php
        $categories_args = array(
            'name'            => $this->get_field_name('posts_cat'),
            'selected'        => $instance['posts_cat'],
            'orderby'         => 'Name',
            'hierarchical'    => 1,
            'show_option_all' => 'All Categories',
            'hide_empty'      => '0'
        );
        wp_dropdown_categories( $categories_args ); ?>
    </p>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select which podcast episode you would like to display:</legend>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('featuretype'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('featuretype'); ?>_val1" value="latest" <?php checked($instance['featuretype'], 'latest'); ?>/>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('featuretype'); ?>_val1">Latest Podcast from Category</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'featuretype' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('featuretype'); ?>_val2" value="featured" <?php checked($instance['featuretype'], 'featured'); ?>/>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('featuretype'); ?>_val2">Featured Podcast (set id below)</label><br />

            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('postid'); ?>">Featured Post's ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('postid') ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('postid') ?> " value="<?php echo $instance['postid'] ?>" size="5">
        </p>
    </fieldset>


    <?php       
        echo '<p><b>';

        if (function_exists('powerpress_init')) 

        echo ' PowerPress is installed. <br />';

        echo '</b></p>';

        echo '<p><b>Widget Shortcode:</b> <code>[featuredpodcast]</code></p>';
    }


    // used when the user saves their widget options
    public function update ($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['showdate'] = $new_instance['showdate'];
        $instance['posts_cat'] = $new_instance['posts_cat'];
        $instance['postid'] = $new_instance['postid'];
        $instance['showsummary'] = $new_instance['showsummary'];
        $instance['showfeatured'] = $new_instance['showfeatured'];
        $instance['featuretype'] = $new_instance['featuretype'];

        return $instance;
    }


    // used when the sidebar calls in the widget
    public function widget ($args, $instance)
    {
        extract($args);

        // Merge with defaults
        $instance = wp_parse_args((array) $instance, $this->defaults);

        echo $before_widget;

        if (!empty($instance['title']))
            echo $before_title . apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base) . $after_title;

        // retrieve post information from database
        if ($instance['featuretype'] == 'featured')
        {
            $query_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'cat'       => $instance['posts_cat'],
                'showposts' => '3',
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, 
                'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', 
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
                'order' => 'DESC'

            );
        }
        else
        {
            $query_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'cat'       => $instance['posts_cat'],
                'showposts' => '3',
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, 
                'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', 
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
                'order' => 'DESC'

            );
        }



        $featured_post = new WP_Query($query_args);

            echo '<img class="headphones-logo" src="';
            echo site_url();
            echo '/wp-content/themes/b4b/images/headphones.png"/>';

        if ($featured_post->have_posts())
        {
            while ($featured_post->have_posts())
            {
                $featured_post->the_post();
                observePostViews(get_the_ID());

                echo '<div class="widget-inner-wrap">';

                if ($instance['showdate']) 
                    echo '<span class="date">';
                    echo get_the_date('m.d.Y', $post->ID);
                    echo '</span>';

                // Show hyperlinked post title
                printf('<h3><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></h3>', get_permalink(), the_title_attribute('echo=0'), get_the_title());

                // If selected, show excerpt from the post
                if ($instance['showsummary'])
                    the_excerpt(); // Show excerpt from the post

                echo '<span class="fp-player">';

                if ($instance['playerwidth'] > 0)
                    $output_text = do_shortcode('[powerpress width="' . $instance['playerwidth'] . '"px]');
                else
                    $output_text = do_shortcode('[powerpress]');

                echo $output_text;
                echo '</span>';

                // printf('<span class="fp-more"><a href="%s">[Read More...]</a></span>', get_permalink());

                echo '</div>';

            }

                echo '<div class="widget-bottom-wrap">';

                echo '<a class="view-more-podcasts" href="';
                echo site_url();
                echo '/category/podcast/">';
                echo "VIEW MORE PODCASTS";
                echo '</a>';

                echo '<a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/bad-4-business/id897719223?mt=2&ign-mpt=uo%3D4">';
                echo '<img class="itunes-widget-logo" src="';
                echo site_url();
                echo '/wp-content/themes/b4b/images/itunes.png"/>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</a>';
        }

        echo $after_widget;
        wp_reset_query();
    }
}


// Hook the widget up to WordPres
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("SEM_Podcast_Widget");'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be fix using session, try following.

Initialize session using following code in your functions.php.

```
    function init_sessions() {
    if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'init_sessions');
```

add a function for setting session

```
function set_session_posts_viewed($postID)
{
    if(empty($_SESSION['posts_viewed']))
    {
        $posts_viewed = array($postID);
        $_SESSION['posts_viewed'] = $posts_viewed;
    }
    else
    {
        $posts_viewed = $_SESSION['posts_viewed'];
        $posts_viewed[] = $postID;
        $_SESSION['posts_viewed'] = $posts_viewed;
    }
}
```

change post count updating code like this

```
function observePostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if(!isset($_SESSION['posts_viewed']) || (isset($_SESSION['posts_viewed']) && !in_array($postID, $_SESSION['posts_viewed'])))
    {
        if($count==''){
            $count = 0;
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
            set_session_posts_viewed($postID);
        }else{
            $count++;
            update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
            set_session_posts_viewed($postID);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it fix the issue. Let me know if you have trouble.